# Structural Mechanics FEM implementation

Tags: mathematica, finite-element-method

I've been trying to create a simple finite element analysis script for determining the strains and stresses in 3-D structures composed of a linearly elastic isotropic material.

I've found a couple of examples of something similar to what I'd like to do [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/structural-mechanics-in-3d.html) 
for the 3D structures, and [also here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) in a simplified 2D version (Go to "Deformation of a Beam under load" section).

My current issue is that I don't understand the equation input as the PDE. It looks like it might be related to the Navier-Cauchy Equation, i.e.

$$\left( \lambda+\mu\right)*\nabla(\nabla \cdot u)+\mu *\nabla^2u+F=0$$
Where:

$\ F$ is the force vector

$\mu$ is the second Lame parameter

$\lambda$ is the first Lame parameter/ Shear Modulus

$\ u$ is the displacement vector.

I'm not totally sure this is the equation used, and if it is I can't figure out how or why it was manipulated into the form used in these examples.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that they have simply written down the operator
$$
\mathrm{div}\,\sigma(u)
$$
explicitly in the corresponding dimensions. In linear elasticity,
$$
\sigma(u) = 2 \mu\,\varepsilon(u) + \lambda\,\mathrm{tr}\,\varepsilon(u) I
$$
and
$$
\varepsilon(u) = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla u + \nabla u^T).
$$
You can find a relationship between the Young's modulus, Poisson ratio $(Y,\nu)$ and the Lame parameters $(\mu,\lambda)$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus#Further_reading) and work out the details by hand or by a CAS.